# How to get SD card sizes (total, used, avaiable) in android app?

Tags: android, android-sdcard, android-external-storage

I'm developing an app and I would insert all the values (total, used and available) about the mounted SD card. I try to use Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), but it shows the values of my internal storage.

Which methods should I use?

Comment: Just a thought, but the device you need might be under /mnt.  That may or may not be dependent on the device.  Linux is fun that way.  Everything can be customized.

Answer (score 0):

```
StatFs class
```

you can use here, provide the path for your internal and external directory and calculate the total, free and avialable space.

```
StatFs memStatus = new    StatFs(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath());
```

See the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StatFs.html) for more details.